# Using "My Maps" with Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

I'm very new to programming and haven't been able to find an answer for this yet. I was wondering if it was possible to use a map that I've already made online through Google (with multiple markers) using the Google map API rather than creating it from scratch again in code.

Comment: Were you able to do this ?

Comment: Have you found the answer? I am too searching for it.